# How to trigger 'Configuration' method in Asp Core Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm unable to trigger 'Configuration' method in my web api core, but i'm able to trigger 'Startup' method. What could be the problem? Please see my code below:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Config { get; }

        //able to trigger this method
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {            
            Config = configuration;
        }

        //cant trigger this method
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
        }

        //able to trigger this method
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        //able to trigger this method
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm platform version? I am seeing code for asp.net-core and Owin start up in asp.net-web-api-2.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Configuration` is not one of the by convention named members associated with `Startup`.

Also `IAppBuilder` is from the previous version of asp.net-web-api and was normally associated with Owin's Startup.

> ### The Startup class
>
> ASP.NET Core apps use a `Startup` class, which is named `Startup` by convention.
>
> The Startup class:
>
> - Can optionally include a `ConfigureServices` method to configure the
>     app's services.
> - Must include a `Configure` method to create the app's
>     request processing pipeline.
>
> `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` are called by the runtime when the app
>   starts:
>
> ```
> public class Startup
> {
>     // Use this method to add services to the container.
>     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
>     {
>         ...
>     }
>
>     // Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
>     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
>     {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

Reference [App startup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2)